# Deciding base resistor for transistor switch circuit

Tags: transistors

I'm building a transistor switch circuit and below is the schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR5QiH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I calculated R2 resistor (base resistor) value from this formula:

$$R_{R2}=\frac{V_{BAT2}-V_{be}}{(V_{BAT1}-V_{ce})/R_{R1}/h_{fe}*2}.$$

Is this enough for this circuit to operate normally in most situation?

Comment: A [manufacturer's datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MM/MMBTA14.pdf) characterises Vce(sat) vs Ic, for Ic/Ib = 1000. I interpret that as a 'hint', by the manufacturer, for the device's intended envelope. So, without any deeper insight, make R2 less resistance than R1*1000 = 70kΩ. Then scale that based on the ratio of BAT2/BAT1. If the circuit is a simplification, and the base will be driven by electronics at some non-trivial frequency, not a human operated switch, then drive it harder, i.e. a lower resistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulation is correct. You must be careful with the \$h_{fe}\$ value you use. Search the device data sheet curve \$h_{fe}\$ vs. collector current, to the value of \$h_{fe}\$ in saturation state.

**EDIT**: from the [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MMBTA13LT1-D.PDF)

[image]

You must use the lower curve to size the output current and by the ratio 
$$
\dfrac{I_C}{I_B}=1000
$$
obtain the required value of base current.
For the saturation condition, the value of \$h_{fe}\$ is lower than for the condition of linear operation, so may the value selected for the base resistance is rather high.

Comment: Thank you for advice. The datasheet curve of \$h_{fe}\$ vs \$I_c\$ is at \$V_{ce}=5V\$, and how can I get \$h_{fe}\$ at my situation?

Comment: The fig 10 of the datasheet from ONsemi, shows the collector-emitter voltage for saturation, at \$\frac{I_C}{I_B}=1000\$ vs collector current. This is the curve you must use.

Comment: 'Ic/Ib = 1000' does it mean that if we know the load current Ic = 0.125mA then we can calculate for lb like this `Ib = 0.125/1000` 0.125uA ?